# armV8 alignment abort

Tags: arm, memory-alignment, abort

When running `strh  r1, [r2]` in armV8, I am receiving the alignment abort with DFSR of 0x801. This is what I expect as the value of `r2` is 0x10074d33 and it's not halfword aligned.

But when I clear the SCTLR.A (alignment checking bit), I still receive the alignment abort! Should I change some other bit somewhere else in other to disable the alignment checking?

Comment: What's the state of the system at this point, and what are the memory attributes of the address you're writing to? (I'll bet 20p you've got the MMU turned off...)

Comment: You are right, problem was page table attributes! But MMU was on so no 20p ;)

Answer (score 3):

Unaligned transfers are not permitted if the memory target is defined as Strongly Ordered or Device.